# Selenium Script To Wrap The calls Java

Tags: java, selenium

i am learning about wrappers and wanted to know how to achieve this task .

Problem : We need selenium script to wrap the calls we have in the attached file.
each call (e.g. fetch) should be a line in the selenium script. quite straight forward.

Now Lines look like this :

```
fetch("http://5.9.140.34:8081/secure/ConfigureTeamsAction.jspa?rapidView=15", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrer":"http://5.9.140.34:8081/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=15&view=planning.nodetail&issueLimit=100","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}); ;
fetch("http://5.9.140.34:8081/s/51a7afa49655351e0828b5c02eddafcd-CDN/9jmibt/802003/7d9ab5157a35650ecc126b476125fb4a/2215ce00ef54a85f6638f0246e6582bf/_/download/contextbatch/css/_super/batch.css", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/css,*/*;q=0.1","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache"},"referrer":"http://5.9.140.34:8081/secure/ConfigureTeamsAction.jspa?rapidView=15","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}); ;
```

I am having problems what should Selenium wrapper do after reading these lines one by one .. according to above problem statement ?

I have done something in java :

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://some.url");

    List formparams = new ArrayList();
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramName", "paramValue"));

    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

But i am not sure how to send requests using Selenium

Comment: What is Selenium wrapper?

Comment: Wrapper means something like in general method . method'd parameters will be those parameters from each line

Comment: So, you are looking for a  java method that will send those requests?

Comment: yeah java with  Selenium

Comment: show your code trials and errors?

Comment: @Dev please recheck question

Comment: @Dev  i am having problem in understanding the problem statement . what do i have to do after reading all the data ? shall i just send request or what ?

Comment: the code you have done in plain java same you want to do with selenium right?

Comment: Selenium is for automating the browser.  Maybe you're looking for something like Postman or Curl:  https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/sending_the_first_request/   https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php